Problem with Database in frame work adoins js
i have error in when i using Database.from , the error is the from is not function
my code :
import vine, { SimpleMessagesProvider } from '@vinejs/vine';
import {Database} from '@adonisjs/lucid/database'

userName: vine.string().unique(async (value, field) => {
        const exists = await Database.from('chef').where('chefUserName', value).first();
        return !exists; // Return true if the username is unique
      }).minLength(4).maxLength(10).regex(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/),


i try to check from package.json if any thing not exist but every thing is fine
